# Wordpress wp_update_post() inserts empty post_title

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the Wordpress theme WPJobus and I had the necessity to modify the workflow of Resume Submission and Resume Editing.

The functions which provide for these operations are located as usual into the file /mytheme/functions.php

```
wpjobusSubmitResumeForm()
wpjobusEditResumeForm()
```

On both of them I have removed the whole code portion which switch post status to "Draft" on every edit occurrence, since I needed to give to the new user the possibility to insert their own posts (Resumes) and publish without the Administrator supervision.

Anyway, I made the all changes and everything works fine except the function wp_update_post() with **posts.post_title** field!

The code looks like this:

```
$post_information = array(
    'ID' => $td_current_post,
    'post_title' => $_POST['fullName'],
    'post_content' => strip_tags($_POST['postContent']),
    'post_type' => 'resume',
    'post_name' => $td_current_post,
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'ping_status' => 'closed',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$td_post_id = wp_insert_post($post_information);

wp_update_post( 
            array(
                'ID' => $td_post_id,
                'post_name' => $td_post_id 
            ) 
);
```

The INSERT works fine but when I call the UPDATE, which is absolutely necessary for post_name field, post_name is correctly updated while post_title value is deleted.

I got the same effect even if I try to pass 'post_title'=>$_POST['fullName'] within wp_post_update array.

Anyone had the same issue?

I also found this but it didn't help at all:
[wp_update_post inserts empty title and content](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_update_post-inserts-empty-title-and-content)

Comment: Why are you setting the `post_name` to be the ID in the update?

Comment: The problem is likely that the theme is inserting itself into the process, but since it is a premium theme, it's not really possible to debug based on the info in your question.

Comment: Hi, 
because it's a default characteristic which comes out with WPJobus theme. After the creation of a new Resume it generates a URL that looks like this:
www.mywebproj.com/resume/$resumeID 

Check this out:
http://alexgurghis.com/themes/wpjobus/resume/565/

Comment: You mean that you need the whole source code in order to analyze it and check for the possible bug... Yes it's a bad issue unfortunately :(

Comment: I would search through all the theme code for "post_title" to see if it is modifying it. It might be using the [pre_post_update](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_post_update) hook.

Comment: I tried to look in the whole theme folder both the keywords post_title and pre_post_update but I didn't get any result. Another big issue is that it's impossible to submit the problem even to the support forum since in order to login it's required the purchase code that is missing cause the theme has been provided by third party company... Pretty annoying stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answer doublesharp!

I finally found the origin of the problem just reading carefully the functions.php file row by row.

The function which was causing the problem is filter_handler() on line 636.

In this case for me it was enough to comment the hook add_filter() related to this function and I achieved the goal.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_handler' , '99', 2 );
```

Now, if I run the script above, **wp_post_update()** works like a charm with **Resume Post Type** ( I guess with Company and Job Post Types as well ).

I will make some more tests and will update this thread in case I would face some unexpected issue.

Here the code of the function:

```
function filter_handler( $data , $postarr ){
global $post, $id;

if(('job' == $data['post_type'] && isset($data['post_type'])) or ('company' == $data['post_type'] && isset($data['post_type'])) or ('resume' == $data['post_type'] && isset($data['post_type']))) {

    $id = $postarr['ID'];

    if($id) {

        $title = $_POST['ID'];
        $wpjobus_title = esc_attr(get_post_meta($title, 'wpjobus_post_title',true));

        if(!empty($wpjobus_title)) {
            $data['post_title'] = $wpjobus_title;
        } else {
            $data['post_title'] = $title;
        }

        $data['post_name'] = $title;
    }

}

return $data; }
```

Another solution should be to force the call of **filter_handler()** Only if the current user is Administrator using the related 'controller':

```
if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
```

For sure the problem is located within that function so any possible correction must be done on it.

Comment: This answer should really be an edit on your question since it provides more information. See my updated answer for the correct way to remove the filter added by your theme.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have provided more information, the correct way to change this behavior is to remove the filter that is being added by your theme, which will give you control of the `post_title`.

```
// add an action after the theme has loaded - wp_loaded is safe
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function(){
    // check for permissions?
    // if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) return;

    // remove the filter that the theme added
    remove_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_handler' , '99', 2 );
} );
```

---

Without access to the source code for your theme it's not possible to say where the error is coming from, however you should be able to use the `pre_update_posts` action to debug, and possibly correct the behavior using the `wp_insert_post_data` filter.

To use the `pre_update_posts` for debugging, you can print the contents of the `$data` array that is used to update the `posts` table, and the `$postarr` array which contains the original fields that you passed in (it can't be modified using filters).

```
// print the $data and $postarr to the error log when inserting/updating
add_action( 'pre_update_posts', function( $data, $postarr ){
    error_log( 'The $data array contains ' . print_r( $data, true ) );
    error_log( 'The $postarr array contains ' . print_r( $postarr, true ) );
}, 100, 2 );
```

The last available place to modify post data that is being inserted/updated is in the `wp_insert_post_data` filter. By attaching to this filter later than everything else, you have the final say in the array values.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', function( $data, $postarr ){
    // you could also log here for debugging
    // error_log( 'The $data array contains ' . print_r( $data, true ) );
    // error_log( 'The $postarr array contains ' . print_r( $postarr, true ) );

    // set the title to whatever was initially passed in
    $data['post_title'] = $postarr['post_title'];

    // return the modified data so that it can be used in the update
    return $data;
}, 999, 2 );
```